# Uninstall or disable Jenkins plugin using terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, jenkins

I installed the Green Balls plugin in Jenkins, but didn't restart after installation, tested to see if it worked but it didn't (successful build icon still blue) so attempted to restart via the browser `localhost:8080/restart`. After waiting for a few minutes Jenkins didn't automatically refresh so I attempted a manual refresh and it was still down. I then attempted to start Jenkins via terminal and it fails to start, stopping Jenkins was successful but it still won't start or restart.
How do I disable or uninstall the plugin without using Jenkins in browser?

Comment: When you restart plugin, what write it in the syslog file?

Comment: My bad, it wasn't the plugin...
`Jenkins requires Java7 or later, but you are runnning 1.6.0_39-b39 from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre`
Although I definitely edited the JAVA_HOME path within Jenkins to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`

Comment: That's ok. Can you write an answer and set it as correct, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jcli to achieve that. https://github.com/jenkins-zh/jenkins-cli

jcli plugin uninstall kubernetes

Comment: how do we get the token parameter that this jcli asks for as the `token` the jenkins provides for the first time we generally does not store .

Can we pass username and password instead of token in jcli ?

Comment: It depends, some old version Jenkins allows it, the new ones don't